# Error: "The instance of entity type 'PO' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for 'prop' is already being tracked

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I am getting the above error when the following code  runs what are my doing wrong?

```
var collectionReport = await _collectionReportRepository.GetAll().FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.PaymentRefNumber == split.PaymentReferenceNumber);

if (collectionReport != null)
{
    collectionReport.IsSplitted = true;

    await _collectionReportRepository.UpdateAsync(collectionReport);


    //Create the child collections in CollectionReportsTable
    // var splitCollections = await GetSplitCollectionReportsByPayRef(collectionReport.PaymentRefNumber);

    var splitCollections = await GetSplitCollectionReportsByPayRef(split.PaymentReferenceNumber);
    var childCollections = SplitExtensions.FromSplitCollectionsToCollections(splitCollections, collectionReport);
    await _collectionReportRepository.SaveRangeAsync(childCollections);
}
```

the methods called above are shown below

```
public async Task<List<SplitCollectionReport>> GetSplitCollectionReportsByPayRef(string payRef) => await _splitCollectionReportRepository.GetAll().Where(c => c.MasterPaymentReferenceNumber == payRef).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
```

```
 public async Task<int> SaveRangeAsync(List<T> range)
        {
            await context.Set<T>().AddRangeAsync(range);
            var saveCount = await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return saveCount;
        }
```

I dont know why its given me the error below

> The instance of entity type 'CollectionReport' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'PaymentRefNumber'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.

Comment: Why is the error in the title different from that in the question body? Does the message **literally** state `{'PaymentRefNumber'}` or did you redact the actual value?

Comment: The title couldn't take all the string

Comment: I asked why it is _different_, not shorter.